# VPC to EC2 Classic Route

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Given:

- **instance-1**: us-east-1c (*not in a VPC*)
- **instance-2**: us-east-1c (*inside my VPC*)

Is there any way to configure a route between the two such that **instance-2** communicates with **instance-1** via the private IP?

I currently have them communicating via the internet gateway using **instance-1**'s public address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is NO. You cannot have such communication route in AWS. The way you are doing it right now via Internet Gateway is the only way.